# How to change fusion table maps markers' size?

Tags: maps, google-fusion-tables

I have a table with a location column and "count" column (with values from 1 to 100).
I'd like to map the records with markers that change in size, i.e. the bigger the count value is, the bigger the marker is.

Is that possible in Google Fusion? How would you suggest to do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are only 2 sizes of icons available: *small* and *large*, I put together a [little example to show you how to use them](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/7xhYG/) together with the [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#FusionTables), which is a special layer for Google Maps that can use to query your Google Fusion Tables.

FusionTablesLayer allow you apply a style to your data (markers, lines or polygons), it boils down to this:

```js
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
        select: 'Location',
        from: '3609183'
    },
    styles: [
       { where: "Number > 1000",
         markerOptions: {
            iconName: 'large_green'
         }
       },
       { where: "Number <= 1000",
         markerOptions: {
            iconName: 'large_red'
         }
       },
       { where: "Number <= 100",
         markerOptions: {
            iconName: 'small_purple'
         }
       }
]});
```

If two sizes are not enough, then maybe you can play around with different colors/icons (there is a [list with supported icons](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA)). Otherwise you have to retrieve your data and [create custom markers](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/custom_markers) with images of different size.

Answer (score 1):

Javram pointed to one approach, but the list of available marker icons is limited in Fusion Tables and AFAIK there is no way to vary the icon size.  Another approach might be to use the JSONP support provided by Fusion Tables to retrieve you your data and create your own makers.  This [blog post](http://www.reddmetrics.com/2011/08/10/fusion-tables-javascript-query-maps.html) explains how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here,  http://support.google.com/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=185991  basically, you need to add a column in your table that is the name of the marker type you want to use for that location.